# Multiprocessing with telegram bot in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing, telegram, telegram-bot

I am making a really big project for my client:
My script has to check the availability of a product on amazon the link of which the user specifies in a telegram bot's chat.
When the script gets a link to be checked for availability It visits that link every 10 minutes with selenium and python and when the product is available even in 2 months. The bot notifies that the product is available.
**The problem is that while the script is searching for availability, it does not read other messages sent to it on telegram until the product is available and it notifies the user. is there a way to:
always read the chat and whenever a time-consuming process is asked for start the action as a separate process.**

Here is my code:

```py
import time
import telebot
import requests
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import random


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)


TOKEN = "MY_TOKEN"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TOKEN)

help = '''
AddCart - Add product (link/links) to cart
Details - Give details of product (link/links)
'''
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help']) # welcome message handler
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, help)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and 'AddCart' in msg.text)
def add_cart(message):
    mes = message.text.replace("AddCart","").replace("\n","").replace(" ","")
    links = mes.split('^^')
    for i in links:
        driver.get(i)
        try:
            addcart = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-to-cart-button"]')
            addcart.click()
            print("Done")
            bot.reply_to(message, "Added to cart")
        except:
            productname = ""
            print("Coulndt do")
            bot.reply_to(message, "Could not add to cart..")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and 'Details' in msg.text)
def scrape_info(message):
    mes = message.text.replace("Details","").replace("\n","").replace(" ","")
    links = mes.split(' ')
    print("DONE")
    for i in links:
        driver.get(i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
    try:
        productname = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]').text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        productname = ""
    try:
        productprice = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]').text
    except:
        try:
            productprice = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_saleprice"]').text
        except:
            productprice = ""
    try:
        stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availability"]/span').text.lower()
    except:
        stock = ""
    try:
        imageurl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="landingImage"]').get_attribute('src')
    except:
        imageurl = ""
    print("Done")
    bot.reply_to(message, f"Name: {productname}\nPrice: {productprice}\nAvailibility: {stock}\n{imageurl}")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and 'CheckAvail' in msg.text)
def check_availibility(message):
    mes = message.text.replace("CheckAvail","").replace("\n","").replace(" ","")
    link = mes
    for i in links:
        driver.get(i)
        time.sleep(600)
        try:
            stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availability"]/span').text.lower()
            if stock=="in stock":
                bot.reply_to(message, "Product is Availible")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            stock = ""

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"[EXCEPTION] {e}")
        time.sleep(15)
```

Can you please help me with this. If there is a solution please edit my script according to the solution.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use python multiprocessing module

Comment: From Review: Please provide some source code to your answer in the context of this question, otherwise this answer would be best suited as a comment.